# SapUI5: How to add buttons dynamically into CutomListItem (xml)?

Tags: sapui5

How can i add **buttons** dynamically to a Custom list item fetching the data from oModel?

XML:

```
<List  items="{msgData>/msgData}" >
<CustomListItem>
    <MessageStriptext="{msgData>Text}"></MessageStrip>


        <List  items="{msgData>buttons}">
            <CustomListItem>
                <Button  text="{text}" press="onFedYes" class="sapUiTinyMarginEnd"/>
            </CustomListItem>
        </List>


</CustomListItem>
</List>
```

JS:

```
    var oModel = this.fragment.getModel("msgData");
        var Buttons = [
            {"text": "Apple"},
            {"text": "Orange"},
            {"text": "Banana"}
        ];

            oModel.oData.msgData.push({
                Type : "Information",
                buttons:Buttons
            }); 
oModel.refresh();
```

UPDATED CODE

Comment: what do you call 'dynamically' ? on user action ?

Comment: IN JAVASCRIPT, attach to the existing model

Comment: do i need to create a new model? i just need to add buttons to the current custom list object

Comment: never modify the model data via the direct manipulation with "oData" property, use "setProperty" for this reason, this would automatically update bindings and you won't need to call "oModel.refresh()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the model your code should look like this

```
    var oModel = this.fragment.getModel("msgData");
    var buttons = oModel.getProperty('/msgData/buttons');
    buttons.push(<..new button..>);
    oModel.setProperty('/msgData/buttons', buttons);
```

this will rerender the list item with the newly added button

Comment: the current XML is ok ? I dont understand your question

Comment: It prints 3 buttons but i cant get the text of each button.... what am i missing here?

Comment: you called the property 'title' and then binded 'text', change your XML accordingly :) <Button text="{title}" />

Comment: iv changed the code, please see it since it output 3 buttons but i cant get the "text" attribute, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: ahh sorry you must put <Button text="{msgData>text}" /> !